# Android Studio wrong file executed

Tags: android-studio

I am beginning to learn developing apps on android studio through android training website. I followed the steps and created an empty project. However I included c++ support while creating project. So when i ran the project, the output is "Hello from c++" from native-lib.cpp instead of "Hello World" in activity_main.xml.

My question is:

How do I get it to execute activity_main.xml and print hello world rather than native-lib.cpp?

Comment: You should show us some code of how are you trying to call your library from the activity. Without this, I doubt we'll be much help.

Comment: I haven't edited anything. Just created the project and ran it without any editing. Its supposed to print "hello world" from activity_main.xml file, but prints "hello from c++" from native-lib.cpp file

Comment: If you changed nothing, why would you expect it to behave differently? It behaves exactly the same as the code you copied, and that's a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860326/android-studio-output-text-always-hello-from-c/52860435#52860435):

If you're just changing the XML, but haven't changed the source code for the new project, then your XML is going to be overridden by the line

`tv.setText(stringFromJNI());`

Remove that line (or set your new text there instead) to fix your issue. It's caused by the fact that the XML is the starting point for your view, so any and all changes to that view during runtime will be the ones that you're likely to see.