# Android Studio output text always 'Hello from C++'

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm facing this weird problem, I've created a `textview` in `activity_main.xml` and set text as: `android:text="Oh my god"`
But **no matter to whatever the text I put, the output in app screen is:**

> Hello from C++

In fact, the position of text changes according to my setting but the text always remains unfortunately unchanged. I've tried removing and again adding `textview` but no change. 
[image]
[image]

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Example of a call to a native method
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
    tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sample_text"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="248dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Oh my god"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

PS: Some guy has this same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837742/android-studio-wrong-file-executed) but wasn't answered yet.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @TheWanderer I've added all, now please take a look.

Comment: try to change it programmatically like textView.setText("Oh my God") ,see if it changes or not,if not ,post your code

Comment: @AdilSaju you're setting the text programmatically. The XML value will be replaced.

Comment: what is this stringFromJNI() , most probably this method returning the string "Hello From C++"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
```

That sets the text to whatever `stringFromJNI()` returns, replacing what you define in the XML.

If you want to change the text that is displayed, either modify the native method to return what you want, remove the programmatic setting, or change what you set the text to in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the text is being changed programatically by an included C++ library. The XML changes are like the initial view's state (set when you inflate the view, or call `setContentView`), and any changes made to that programmatically with override it.

If you comment out the line

`tv.setText(stringFromJNI());`

You'll see your XML changes remain, and the textview will show your XML text string instead (because it will no longer be being set after the view is initially created).

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: Just added edited my answer, but basically don't set the text programatically if you only want to set it in the XML.