# Why is it that when I run this code, I get "Hello from C++" on my android emulator?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-emulator

When I run the code down below, I get "Hello from C++" instead of the expected "Hello World!" on my USB connected android phone and emulator. Why is that?

I've tried running it on both my android phone and an android emulator (PIXEL XL API 28) and they both output the same thing, "Hello form c++"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sample_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That is your layout, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53908097/edit) your question to include your Android Java code.

Comment: The answer is here:
[Android Studio output text always 'Hello from C++'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860326/android-studio-output-text-always-hello-from-c) Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you both, I've fixed my problem.